# Changed value of attribute using an angular directive

Tags: angularjs

So what i want is to pass a variable for maxlength property of an input

```
  <input my-dir="maxLenght" id="inputScannedCode"
         type="text" ng-model="ScannedCode" maxlength="20"
         class="form-control orange-shadow" 
         required placeholder=" Scan the code " />
```

So i want the length of the input to be set from a constant for consistency.

so i've created a custom directive so that it changes the maxlength value.

```
.directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myDir: '='
        },
        template: '<div>{{myindex}}</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //console.log(attrs);
            //attrs.maxlength = scope.myDir.toString();
            //attrs.placeholder = scope.myDir.toString();            
        }          
    };
})
```

Indeed this changes my maxlength value but it does after compile but when i inspect my element it still shows maxlengh="20".

Any ideas what i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interpolation:

```
  <input my-dir="maxLenght" id="inputScannedCode"
         type="text" ng-model="ScannedCode" 
         maxlength="{{maxLenght || '20'}}"
         class="form-control orange-shadow" 
         required placeholder=" Scan the code " />
```

The $compile service will create a watcher that updates the maxlength attribute each time the Angular expression changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might need to compile it using scope.eval in the link function like this to retrieve your value as you're using it in the link function

   attrs.myDir = scope.$eval(attrs.myDir);`
2. And you are never setting the maxLength property on the input: you can use ng-maxlength for this: ([angular documentation)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength) which is the main reason it isn't updating

   ```
   <input my-dir="maxLenght" ng-maxlength="maxLength" id="inputScannedCode" type="text" ng-model="ScannedCode"  class="form-control orange-shadow" required placeholder=" Scan the code " />
   ```
3. In your example you also misspelled "maxLength" as "maxLenght"

Comment: the problem is from what i could tell that maxLength is set to (let's say) 5 after the HTML page is rendered so the atribute keeps his original value ( logic ... ). I don't want to use ng-maxlength becouse this only makes the form that is nesting the input to be invalid, but it does allow user to exceed the number of chars set.